# Ajax form Issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do a simple ajax form post.  I think there is an issue with my code at the $.ajax lines.  Once the code hits the $.ajax portion, console.log() fails to work and the form just redirects conventionally to the ajax-report-comment.php page and not through ajax.  Up to this part my console.log function reports data and doesn't redirect to the page.

Does any one see what I am doing wrong here?  Essentially on success I want it to alert the user of successful report.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function() {

    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        method = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] =  value;        
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    return false;   


});
});

</script>   
</head>
<body>  

<form method="post" action="ajax-report-comment.php" class="ajax">
    <input type="submit" value="Report" />
    <input class="field" type="hidden" name="report_user_id" id="report_user_id" value="5"/>
    <input class="field" type="hidden" name="report_comment_id" id="report_comment_id" value="33543"/>
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure `return false;` to cancel default actions is deprecated in modern versions of jQuery (if you use the `migrate` plugin, you will see warnings about that), so you should use:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // the rest of your code
```

Comment: This could be the reason as recently I also was having similar issue with `return false` and `preventDefault()` worked.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, I followed your instruction and it looks like i have an error:  Uncaught ReferenceError: type is not defined demo.php:31
(anonymous function) demo.php:31
x.event.dispatch jquery-1.10.2.js:5095
v.handle

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to @jeroen answer a bit:

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) as he suggests, but also check into [.serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

You could replace this entire block of code (from your code above):

```
// Replace this entire block with jQuery's serialize
that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();

        data[name] =  value;        
    });
```

With:

```
var data = $(this).serialize();
```

Comment: Will try the serialize method.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeroen I was able to find that error of anonymous function.  I had method where I should have had type in the var.

Corrected functioning js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('form.ajax').on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] =  value;        
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

    return false;   


});
});
```